# Error executing DDL Id not null via JDBC Statement

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to do One To Many Mapping from User_details Table to Vehicle_details Table.This Error Occurred. *"Error executing DDL "alter table vehicle_detail add vehicle_id number(10,0) not null" via JDBC Statement"*
I think this error is because of Generated Value annotation.
How to solve this.

User_details.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_Detail")
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    int u_id;
    String u_name;
    String u_email;
    int mob_no;
    String gender;
    int age;
    String city;
    String State;
    int pincode;
    String address;
    String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_user_id",referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicle;

    }
```

Vehicle.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GeneratorType;

@Entity
@Table(name="Vehicle_detail")
public class Vehicle {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="vehicle_id")
    private int vid;
    
    private String vname;
    private String vmodel;
    private String showroomprice;
    private String onroadprice;
    private long aadharcardno;
    private String pancardno;
    private boolean photo;
    private String employmenttypes;
    private boolean salaryslip;
    private int annualsalary;
    private boolean existingemi;
}
```

Error

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table vehicle_detail add vehicle_id number(10,0) not null" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.lti.VehicleLoanApplication.main(VehicleLoanApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:299) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: In the db are there any data? If no data can recreate rather than update existing tbl schemas

Comment: Check whether vehicle details table has vehicle_id column?

Comment: Yes ,it has vehicle_id column

Comment: Your database is telling you, that it can't run the `alter table` command within the configured timeout. Seems like it can't acquire an exclusive lock on the table. But regardless, don't run hbm2ddl migrations in your application. The migration will fail anyway if you have data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to hibernate dependencies in your pom.xml page

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: doesn't change anything for me